# IDE doesn't find the declared global types

Tags: typescript, types, import, tsconfig

I have a global typing file where I define my types, variables etc...

Now the project structure is like this:

```
trunk
   typings
     index.d.ts
   src
     Example.ts
     Example.d.ts
   tsconfig.json
```

In `index.d.ts` I have let's say

```
declare type userInfo = {
    username: string,
    password: string,
}
```

But in `Example.d.ts` when I use `userInfo` directly IDE says it cannot find the name whereas the tsc compiler shows no error.

```
declare class Something {
   ...
   getUserInfo: () => userInfo; // <--- this is highlighted red
}
```

The funny thing is that when I use `userInfo` in `Example.ts` there is no highlighted errors.

Another funny thing is when I `go to the declaration` it jumps to correct line in `index.d.ts`

I don't import the types in neither files as they are `global` types.

My `tsconfig` file is like below:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "typeRoots": ["./typings"],
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

What may be the problem?

Comment: I can reproduce this in Visual Studio Code.  It looks like when Example.ts exists, Example.d.ts is no longer treated as part of the project; `tsc` doesn't even read it (which explains the lack of errors there), and when I open it in Visual Studio Code, it doesn't see other files.  I don't think users are expected to have both Example.ts and Example.d.ts.  Why do you have both?

Comment: You can add 
/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />
to your Example.d.ts file. I recommend you to submit a bug to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not declare types. Declare is useful when you want to indicate that there is some *javascript* class in global variable scope (and hence, Typescript is not able to see it). e.g. :

```
declare class UserInfo {...} // typings.d.ts
```

Now what you should use instead is just regular `type`

```
type UserInfo = {...} // Example.ts
```

Even better, I'd suggest to you use interface in your case, because the UserInfo type seems to be simple:

```
// Example.ts
interface UserInfo {
  username: string,
  password: string,
}
```

Feel free to ask me if you don't get something

Comment: @jackop did you remove the `example.d.ts` as well? And did you import the `UserInfo` interface? TypeScript code doesn't require d.ts files and the type information on any types I declare and import is always available for me in VS Code. This is the correct answer.

Comment: @jackjop you NEED to import interface if it is located in `.ts` file. You DO NOT NEED to import it when it is located in `d.ts` file. `MediaStream` lives in `node_modules/typescript/lib.dom.d.ts`, that's why you are able to use it without importing. For some reason I always placed my interfaces in `.ts` file, maybe because I like things to be explicit, and do not like global stuff. As I know many developers use the same approach. IMHO you should do the same, unless your app is really tiny and you are sure there will be no two interfaces with the same name.

Comment: Using global names is simply a bad practice. Think about it: maybe you have errors because what you trying to do is just not mainstream/best practice, hence only you have this problem. Anyway, I gave you solution and advice from my experinece (more than 12 years). You rejected it. Therefore, it seems I cannot help you.

Comment: This doesn't answser the question. TS does support global.d.ts for a reason